# How to make data remain after success validation?

Tags: validation, jsp, struts, textfield

I have jsp using struts bean tag library:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">

</head>
<body>
<p><a class="colorGrey" href="Welcome.do">
    <bean:message key="menu.label" />
</a> &gt;&gt;<bean:message key="menu.link.addnews" /> </p>
<p><br>
</p>

<html:form action="/NewsSave">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td class="colorGrey" width="164" height="35">
    <bean:message key="body.news.title" />  </td>
<td width="577">
    <html:text property="newsTitle"  size="40" value=""/>    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <html:errors property="newstitle" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="colorGrey">
    <bean:message key="body.news.date" />   </td>
<td>
    <html:text property="newsDate" size="10" value=""/>    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td height="21" colspan="2" valign="top">
    <html:errors property="newsdate" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="colorGrey" height="61" valign="top">
    <bean:message key="body.news.brief" />  </td>
<td valign="top">
    <html:textarea property="brief" cols="40" rows="6" value=""/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td height="23" colspan="2" valign="top"><html:errors property="brief" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="colorGrey" height="100" valign="top">
    <bean:message key="body.news.content" />
</td>
<td valign="top">
    <html:textarea property="content" cols="40" rows="12" value=""/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="23" colspan="2" valign="top">
    <html:errors property="content" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<html:submit value="SAVE"/>
</html:form>
<form method="POST" 
action="Link.do?method=newsList"
onsubmit="return confirm('<bean:message key="body.onsubmit.cancel" />')">
<input type="submit" value="CANCEL">
</form>
```

And I use validator plugin, which means that after receiving incorrect info it gives message bellow text field telling what's wrong. But problem is that everything disappear after submiting. So it no info in `text` or `text-area`tags. I know that it happens because of `value=""`. But I have another page with the same fields for adding info, which should be clear from the beginning. And if I remove `value=""`, the info from this fields will be displayed on that page after forwarding. So

1. What should I do to clear info from forms after forwarding to
   another page?
2. How to make info remain after success validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you should remove value="" as this is setting the fields to empty. If you want to clear the values then you should do this in the Action class in which your Form bean is populated.
If you are finding that your Form beans are retaining their values between requests then check that they are request scope: the scope attribute of the action element should be "request" in struts.config

Comment: Btw, info about scope was the key one